# FindFirst and orElse operators return different class type

Tags: groovy, java-8, java-stream

I´m using Stream with `findFirst()` which returns `Optional`, but also there´s a chance where my `Stream` maybe does not emit anything, so I added the `orElse` operator at the bottom.

The problem is that `orElse` does not return an optional but the class type that the optional `findFirst` operator wrap.

```
        def optional = categories.categories.stream()
                .filter { category -> category.name == selCategory }
                .map { category -> loadUniqueIds.call(category) }
                .map { UUIDs -> new JsonArray(UUIDs) }
                .findFirst().orElse{Optional.of(new JsonArray())}
        optional.get()
```

So I end up without the possibility of use `findFirst` and `orElse`.

What I´m doing wrong here?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I end up removing the `orElse` after the `findFirst` and check the optional later

```
        optional.isPresent() ? optional.get(): new JsonArray()
```

Anyway if somebody has a better/elegant solution, please let me know.

Regards.

Comment: What is `def optional` supposed to be in Java?

Comment: This is groovy but I´m using Java 8 stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `findFirst()` you get an `Optional`, but if you use `orElse()` (which is `Optional`'s method) you get the unwrapped object, since there's no way you can get an `Optional` anymore. Either you get what was found in `findFirst()` unwrapped *or* you get the "default" value from `orElse()`.

It doesn't make sense to return an optional from `orElse()`, because it's always guaranteed to exist.

```
Optional.of("foo").orElse("bar");  // Returns String "foo"
Optional.empty().orElse("bar");    // Returns String "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, that´s what I though

Comment: probably best to use `orElseGet { -> new JsonArray() }` in this case, so you don't make a new one every time it's called no matter what